# What does "tweak business establishment" mean here?

Tags: phrases, context, comprehension

everyone, I have difficulities in understanding the following sentence.

> All the while, the flamboyant and irreverent Mr. Branson has tweaked the **business establishment**, particularly in Britain, and displayed a good command of publicity and **showmanship** to gain priceless cachet for the Virgin brand.

(source: https://www.strategy-business.com/article/13416?gko=74f03)

I have two questions:

The first one is: what does "business establishment" mean here? Literally, it means the place that a business is conducted. But it doesn't seem to fit here. It should be the way of doing practice since he is irreverent, or something like that.

Second question is: does publicity and showmanship means the same thing. Basically, he has a good command of the interest of the public, so he can lead their opinions (showmanship).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*What does business establishment mean here?*

*The business establishment* refers here not to a place of doing business, but to the established businesses in a particular line of trade and, even more so, to the people who run these enterprises.

*Publicity* and *showmanship* are not the same. Effective publicity includes the conventional means of communicating with potential consumers. Showmanship is finding a more dramatic or unusual means of attracting attention to the product. In one of these bits of showmanship, according to the article you cite, Branson is said to have driven a tank down a major thoroughfare.

Comment: So can I say "tweak the business establishment" means he moves to change/improve the rules in a particular industry.

Comment: You didn’t ask about tweak. According to the story, the establishment took notice, but Brennan was looking for business opportunities where he could provide a better product or service at a reasonable price. Tweak is informal.